# Microsoft Access Forms with SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

We are maintaining Microsoft Access 2016 database for Locker Management Inventory. The database contains complex queries (Computed Columns) , Reports and Database backend file is also on the same computer. 
We are required to use SQL Server Management Studio 2012 as our Back-end for Microsoft Access Forms and this form is required to be accessed by 10 Users on LAN. Please guide Step by Step Procedure for this task.

Thanks in Anticipation.

Comment: Is this a question about migrating an MS Access database to SQL server?

Comment: Yes. But in Addition I need help on Accessing back-end by multiple users on LAN.

Comment: SSMS is no backend, it's a frontend for SQL Server. Doesn't matter though, this question is way too broad and off-topic here.

Comment: Andre..... The Question is very Straight Forward and to the point. Let me explain... I need a Central Database for MS Access Form to be shared on LAN. The Database would be stored in SQL server.

Comment: If you used linked tables in your access application to SQL server, then you can simply distribute that resulting application and place a copy on each workstation. So  you migrate the data to SQL server, then use the linked table manager in Access to link to the tables on SQL server and you are quite much good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Access is inherently multi user and has no problem linking to tables on a SQL Server that is on the same LAN.

The design steps are typically to design the application in Access, unsplit, in a single file.  Then when the app is ready - one splits the file into a back end and front end that are linked.  One can copy the front end multiple times for multiple users.

These steps above are all Access and you'll find good documentation online and in any textbook for the Access database.

The final step, if one must use SQL Server as the back end, is to then import those tables from the Access back end file into the SQL Server.  This is not uncommon but the instructions for this would be in SQL Server area.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I Appreciate your Detailed Answer. But I need Clarification in few Areas:  I have installed SQL server on my Machine And I want to  Distributed Copies of MS Access Forms to 05 Colleagues. But those people dont have MS SQL Server installed on their PCs. How would they communicate with the SQL server installed on my Machine??.

Comment: Well it is assumed that you have a dedicated machine that has the running instance of SQL server. And you can use that computer for sharing of folders and files etc. Such a computer does not necessary have to be a "server" based edition of windows but in all practical cases it would be some machine dedicated for this purpose.  While  you certainly can run SQL server on your computer and have all others connect to that instance of SQL, it not that practical since things like re-boot or shutting down your computer would break the connection for all those users.

Comment: SQL server native Client has resolved my issue/problem. I have installed SQL server native client on all workstations and have configured ODBC with SQL Server. It Works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

One must understand the fundamental architecture: a multi user Access application is 2 files: front and back (this is actually what they are called).  There is only 1 back file - it is where the tables are held.  The front file can be copied repeatedly, 1 per user, and all fronts link to the single back end file.

SQL Server is the back end and Access is the front end - in your case.

One only really needs the SQL Server product as the back end file if the payload is particularly high.  Pay load is combination of the quantity of records and simultaneous users.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach is to split your database into two parts. A built in database splitter is built into Access. Once done, you could in theory just place the back end accDB access file on some server folder that is shared to everyone. You then use the linked table manager in Access to link to the back end file.

Since you been “mandated” to use SQL server, then you would migrate the back end accDB file tables to sql server, and then re-link (again use the built in table manager) to link the tables to SQL server. So the process for linking to an access file, or linking to sql server is near identical. The end result is your access application will now be using tables that reside on SQL server. From a developer and even user point of view your forms, code, reports etc. will continue to run as before.

And as a general rule it only makes sense to run SQL server on your machine for development use. You would have to copy/transfer the sql database to that “mandated” instance of SQL server they are telling you to use that presumably is running on some server. It would not make sense to mandate use of SQL server without you being provided with some server running SQL server.

It certainly is possible to allow users to connect to YOUR computer running SQL server, but that seems less than ideal since if you re-boot, shut down or your computer freezes, then all other users would suffer a connection break and much inconvenience.

I mean, right now if you have a shared folder for all users, such folders are typically NOT placed on one users computer, but some dedicated machine that acts as some kind of server for everyone.

So if they are telling you to use SQL server, then it quite much assumed they are providing a dedicated machine that is running SQL server. So certainly for development you can (and even should) run SQL server on your machine. However you would then have to transfer that database to the computer/server they are telling you to use with SQL server. And then you would re-link your Access application tables to now point to that production server. The last step would be to then distribute this correctly linked application to each user. So just like all software you purchase such as word, or Excel, you STILL install that software on each computer. Now that you are building software, then you as a developer will adopt the same concept – that is to distribute and install your software on each workstation. So while you might use word or Excel (or Access) from the local computer, you also may well often “share” some data files (but NOT the application) on the server.

As long as the application you distribute to each workstation is correctly linked and points to the server based edition of SQL server, then you all be sharing the same database. You will NOT in practice have multiple users working on and using the application you created, but distribute that Access application to each workstation. How you “get” that application to each workstation is not really any different then how you would supply a word document or Excel sheet – the only requirement here being that each workstation gets their own copy. Since each users copy of this application has linked tables that point to SQL server, then you all working on and sharing a common database.

So the first concept to grasp is that of spitting a database. I explain this concept here:

http://www.kallal.ca/Articles/split/index.htm

As for some steps and migrating to sql server, here is a great starting point:

https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/index.html

Comment: Sir You are explaining something I have already completed. My Access  db is split between front-end (Forms, Queries, Reports) and Backend (tables in SQL server)..... The only issue is in knowing how would other clients link to the central DB (SQL server installed on dedicated machine)???? Should I use SQL server Native Client ??

Comment: Once you linked the table(s), then you can distribute that pre linked application to each workstation and they will be pointing to that SQL back end. So only a one time link is required. If SQL tables have any “newer” columns such as datetime2, then you HAVE to install the native 11 (or later) driver on each workstation for Access to correctly use such columns, and of course during linking choose the native 11 driver. So if possible use the standard SQL driver during linking and thus no additional software install or setup will be required on each workstation.